# Can a class instantiate itself?

Tags: java, oop

I was looking at example code on a [website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm).  Here is a snippet,

```
public class ManageEmployee {
   private static SessionFactory factory; 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
         factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      }catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }
      ManageEmployee ME = new ManageEmployee();

      /* Add few employee records in database */
      Integer empID1 = ME.addEmployee("Zara", "Ali", 1000);
      Integer empID2 = ME.addEmployee("Daisy", "Das", 5000);
      Integer empID3 = ME.addEmployee("John", "Paul", 10000);
```

Why is this class calling itself?  Looks like it would just keep calling itself in a loop.  What is this class doing here, `ManageEmployee ME = new ManageEmployee();`?  Thanks.

Comment: The main method is called once. Where do you think there is a loop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not uncommon for a `main` method to create a new instance of the class it's defined in. But creating an instance won't call `main` again. Remember, `main` is a static method, not tied to any particular instance.

Answer (score 5):

The key point that other members here aren't mentioning is that running a program and instantiating a class are two different things.  When you wrote Hello World in java, you wrote the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

The main method runs when you execute the class containing it.  However, within this main method (in a static context), you can do the following:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This is called instantiating, and here we are instantiating an `ArrayList` with type `String`.  When this occurs, the main method inside `ArrayList` is not called - instead, its constructor is.  Thus, in our main method we can instantiate the class that contains the main method and it calls the constructor, not the main method:

```
public class TestClass {
    public TestClass(String greeting) {
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
         TestClass c = new TestClass("Hello World");
    }
}
```

"Hello World" will be printed once, when the constructor is called from within the main method.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's absolutely no problem with a class's methods calling itself,

And no, it won't loop, because instantiating a class doesn't automatically invoke all of its methods.

The reason why the `main` method gets run at all is because Java looks for a single `main` method as its entry point.

`main` is a `static` method, therefore it's not associated with any instance anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The Method is called only one time, at program start normally.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

In this your program creates an object from type **ManageEmploye**, so can access to its **non-static** properties